# PhoneGap plugins does not work (undefined)

Tags: plugins, cordova

I’m developing my first app over PhoneGap and I’m really stuck with very frustrating plugin issues.

I’ll explain the problem with samples from Phonegap Docs in order to avoid code issues on my side. This is the workflow I’m following for create the app from scratch and add the plugins:

```
$ phonegap create helloworld com.phonegap.helloworld HelloWorld
[phonegap] created project at /.../Phonegap_Dev/helloworld
$ cd helloworld/
$ cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
Preparing ios project
$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
Preparing android project
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
Fetching plugin from "org.apache.cordova.dialogs"...
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" for android
Preparing android project
org.apache.cordova.dialogs installed on android.
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" for ios
Preparing ios project
org.apache.cordova.dialogs installed on ios.
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
Fetching plugin from "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"...
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" for android
Preparing android project
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen installed on android.
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" for ios
Preparing ios project
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen installed on ios.
```

Once I’ve got this basic phonegap-generated app, I change the contents in the file www/index.html for the example code from Phonegap documentation about SplashScreen plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Splashscreen Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.alert(“Alert works…!!”);
        navigator.splashscreen.show();
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and compile the app with:

```
$ cordova build
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project
Compiling app on platform "android" via command "/Users/ifernandez/Duonet_Dev/Phonegap_Dev/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
Compiling app on platform "ios" via command "/Users/ifernandez/Duonet_Dev/Phonegap_Dev/helloworld/platforms/ios/cordova/build" 
Platform "android" compiled successfully.
Platform "ios" compiled successfully.
```

Now, when I test the app with Ripple Emulator, the alert shows correctly, but the call to splashscreen.show() always return:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined

so looks like the app is not finding the splashscreen plugin despite all looks correct inside plugins folder.

Why this simple example does not work? Are my workflow missing some step? Missing aditional configuration? Can some plugins be checked and debugged in Ripple and others not...?

I’ve passed last couple of days trying to find out where is the problem without luck...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You create your app using phonegap and then use cordova for other commands. It is recommended to use either phonegap or cordova, but nox mix using both. I suspect your plugin not correctly installed. Do you see it in plugins/android.json and can you find it in subfloders of platforms\android\assets\www\plugins ?